# How to separate production and development code in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I haven't found any proper answer to this sadly.

I'm currently developing a react-native app with `redux` and I found out that the release version is getting slowed down by some development tools.

Here's an example:

```
const store = createStore(
  Reducers,
  composeWithDevTools(
    applyMiddleware(thunk),
  ),
);
```

And this `composeWithDevTools` is obviously some development tool and in `release` I should use another function called `compose`.
What I'd like to do would be something like this:

```
//development
const store = createStore(
  Reducers,
  composeWithDevTools(
    applyMiddleware(thunk),
  ),
);
//production
const store = createStore(
  Reducers,
  composeWithDevTools(
    applyMiddleware(thunk),
  ),
);
//end
```

It would automatically choose the right code sample considering where I am. (Dev or release).

Do you guys know some tool I could use for this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This tool worked for me: https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0596/9309/products/Narrow-10-Tine-Garden-Rake-by-Sneeboer-z-1.jpg?v=1426088194

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `__DEV__` global constant. Moreover, babel compiler smart enough to completely remove code guarded by constants, so you also can reduce code size.

For example, we use this code to initialize store:

```js
function setupStore(extra = {}) {
  const middlewares = [thunk.withExtraArgument(extra)]
  if (__DEV__) {
    const createLogger = require('redux-logger').createLogger // redux-logger 3.x
    const logger = createLogger()
    middlewares.push(logger)
  }
  const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(...middlewares), autoRehydrate())
  return store
}
```

Comment: It works actually ! I got an `eslint` error on this but whatever, I'll figure it out :P
Thanks :)

Comment: this gives me an error, `Uncaught TypeError: createLogger is not a function`. could you please check this ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Redux Logger has been changed a little while ago.

Now you need to import like this: 
`import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';`

In the example above you can do something like this:

```
const { createLogger } = require('redux-logger');
const logger = createLogger();
middlewares.push(logger);
```